# how does the for each method in underscore.js work?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In underscore.js the for each method starts with the following:

```
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
```

How is it able to do something = something = something? I didn't think you could do that?

See: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-12

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's basically just defining aliases for the `function(obj, iterator, context)` that is created.

It's the same as doing `var a = b = c = d = 0;` All those vars are created and have the value 0.

Though the example I gave will actually create separate objects because a number is an intrinsic type. The one in your question will create those objects that all reference the same function.

Comment: var a = b = c = d = 0; - this will create b,c,d vars in global scope. Not very good way.

Comment: @Flops I never said creating global variables was a good idea. Just that you can do multiple assignment like that.

Comment: I didn't want to say something that you've doing somthing bad. I just wanted to describe a problem that will be if you'll use this pattern.

Comment: I agree completely. I was just assuming that people would read it as an example of assignment not a recommendation for how to write a .js file. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's mean that there is creating one local function each for local functions, and creating _.each and _.forEach methods in 'Underscore' scope. Thats all. 
It`s like

```
var a , b, c;
a = b = c = 3;
console.log(a,b,c) // 3,3,3
```